# Group array of objects into specific format

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, grouping

I have an array of objects in this format:

```
const arr = [
    {
        parentKey: {
            myKey1: 'someStringA',
            myKey2: 'anotherStringA',
            myKey3: false,
            myKey4: true
        },
        anotherKey: {}
    },
    {
        parentKey: {
            myKey1: 'someStringA',
            myKey2: 'anotherStringA',
            myKey3: true,
            myKey4: false
        },
        anotherKey: {}
    },
    {
        parentKey: {
            myKey1: 'someStringA',
            myKey2: 'anotherStringA',
            myKey3: true,
            myKey4: false
        },
        anotherKey: {}
    },
    {
        parentKey: {
            myKey1: 'someStringA',
            myKey2: 'anotherStringA',
            myKey3: true,
            myKey4: true
        },
        anotherKey: {}
    },
    {
        parentKey: {
            myKey1: 'someStringA',
            myKey2: 'anotherStringB',
            myKey3: true,
            myKey4: true
        },
        anotherKey: {}
    },
    {
        parentKey: {
            myKey1: 'someStringB',
            myKey2: 'anotherStringB',
            myKey3: false,
            myKey4: true
        },
        anotherKey: {}
    }
];
```

And I need to get a result in this format:

```
const result = [
    {
        props: {
            myKey1: 'someStringA',
            myKey2: 'anotherStringA',
            myKey3: false,
            myKey4: true
        },
        entries: [
            {
                parentKey: {
                myKey1: 'someStringA',
                myKey2: 'anotherStringA',
                myKey3: false,
                myKey4: true
                },
                anotherKey: {}
            }
        ] 
    },
    {
        props: {
            myKey1: 'someStringA',
            myKey2: 'anotherStringA',
            myKey3: true,
            myKey4: false
        },
        entries: [
            {
                parentKey: {
                myKey1: 'someStringA',
                myKey2: 'anotherStringA',
                myKey3: true,
                myKey4: false
                },
                anotherKey: {}
            },
            {
                parentKey: {
                    myKey1: 'someStringA',
                    myKey2: 'anotherStringA',
                    myKey3: true,
                    myKey4: false
                },
                anotherKey: {}
            }
        ] 
    },
    {
        props: {
            myKey1: 'someStringA',
            myKey2: 'anotherStringA',
            myKey3: true,
            myKey4: true
        },
        entries: [
            {
                parentKey: {
                    myKey1: 'someStringA',
                    myKey2: 'anotherStringA',
                    myKey3: true,
                    myKey4: true
                },
                anotherKey: {}
            }
        ] 
    },
    {
        props: {
            myKey1: 'someStringA',
            myKey2: 'anotherStringB',
            myKey3: true,
            myKey4: true
        },
        entries: [
            {
                parentKey: {
                    myKey1: 'someStringA',
                    myKey2: 'anotherStringB',
                    myKey3: true,
                    myKey4: true
                },
                anotherKey: {}
            }
        ] 
    },
    {
        props: {
            myKey1: 'someStringB',
            myKey2: 'anotherStringB',
            myKey3: false,
            myKey4: true
        },
        entries: [
            {
                parentKey: {
                    myKey1: 'someStringB',
                    myKey2: 'anotherStringB',
                    myKey3: false,
                    myKey4: true
                },
                anotherKey: {}
            }
        ] 
    }
];
```

I am trying to write a function groupArray which will group array of object based on array of keys provided, e.g., `groupArray(arr, ['parentKey.myKey1', 'parentKey.myKey2', 'parentKey.myKey3', 'parentKey.myKey4'])` but haven't succeeded. Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vk2xqrc4/1/) with my code. All entries are currently placed in resulting array without being grouped.

Could you give me hint how to fix my function.

Comment: Hi not sure what you mean, are you trying to group the objects together? The result format you provided just restructures the original list with no grouping

Comment: The entries are grouped by the keys provided. If you check the result you will see that second object of the `result` includes 2 objects from the original array `arr`. I am trying to archive something similar to what [group-array package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/group-array) does but without nesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a hash table for grouping the same group and a function for getting a value out of an object with it's path through the nested properties.

```js
function groupArray(array, keys) {
    function getValue(object, path) {
        return path.split('.').reduce((o, k) => (o || {})[k], object);
    }

    var hash = Object.create(null),
        result = [];

    array.forEach(function (o) {
        var key = keys.map(k => getValue(o, k)).join('|');
        if (!hash[key]) {
            hash[key] = { props: Object.assign(...keys.map(k => ({ [k.split('.').pop()]: getValue(o, k) }))), entries: [] };
            result.push(hash[key])
        }
        hash[key].entries.push(o);
    });
    return result;
}

var array = [{ parentKey: { myKey1: 'someStringA', myKey2: 'anotherStringA', myKey3: false, myKey4: true }, anotherKey: {} }, { parentKey: { myKey1: 'someStringA', myKey2: 'anotherStringA', myKey3: true, myKey4: false }, anotherKey: {} }, { parentKey: { myKey1: 'someStringA', myKey2: 'anotherStringA', myKey3: true, myKey4: false }, anotherKey: {} }, { parentKey: { myKey1: 'someStringA', myKey2: 'anotherStringA', myKey3: true, myKey4: true }, anotherKey: {} }, { parentKey: { myKey1: 'someStringA', myKey2: 'anotherStringB', myKey3: true, myKey4: true }, anotherKey: {} }, { parentKey: { myKey1: 'someStringB', myKey2: 'anotherStringB', myKey3: false, myKey4: true }, anotherKey: {} }],
    result = groupArray(array, ['parentKey.myKey1', 'parentKey.myKey2', 'parentKey.myKey3', 'parentKey.myKey4']);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```